# My Pagination From Search Results does not work?

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

```
<?php
include 'connectsqli.php';
$country=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_GET['country']));
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_GET['city']));

    $tableName="user";      
    $targetpage = "result_members.php";     
    $limit = 2; 
    $search ="";
    $search .= " WHERE country LIKE '".$country."' AND city LIKE '".$city."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName ".$search);
    $total_pages = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    $page = mysqli_escape_string($con,$_GET['page']);
    if($page){
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
    }else{
        $start = 0; 
        }   
    // Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName ".$search." LIMIT $start, $limit";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query1);

    // Initial page num setup
    if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
    $prev = $page - 1;  
    $next = $page + 1;  


    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    


    $paginate = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
        // Previous
        if ($page > 1){
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }

        // Next
        if ($page < $lastpage){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
            }
        $paginate.= "</div>";           
}
?>
<?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            //display data
        }
 echo "<div class='pagee'>".$paginate."</div>";
?>
```

I'm new with PHP and MySQLi. this is my search result page.

It's working for the first page and when I click on the next page it is not working...

I'm search on google and some say I need to use `http_build_query` to store my variables of `$country` and `$city`.

Anyone can help me to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the value of $page.

Comment: You can use `var_dump($page);` just before the `if ($page){` statement. That will give you an 'ugly' variable dump of $page on your page.

Comment: give me this string(0)

Comment: if i click next again and give me string(1) "2"

Comment: My previous conclusion was wrong. 2 is correct for the page number.  You can var_dump($query1) and execute the result in your database to see if the query has a result or errors.

Comment: here how it give me "SELECT * FROM user WHERE city LIKE 'Melbourne' AND country LIKE 'Australia' LIMIT 1, 2"

Comment: And when you execute this statement manually in your database (I do not know which database you are using, MySql?), do you get results or an error?

Comment: no error from there. it display results 13 members but when i click next page and its display 600 members (all from table USER)

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought nothing was shown (not working). Ok, but that is because all your pagination links only contain the page number and not the country and city. Add that to all your pagination links.

Comment: Like `?page=$page&country=$country&city=$city`